# How to add a foreign key from multiple options available in model for that key in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

models.py

```
class Currency(models.Model):
    currency_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)

class Address(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.common.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    currency_names = models.ForeignKey(Currency, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    zebpay = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
```

This is the model that I have for adding an address of an exchange. Every address will be saved in respective exchanges's form field.

There are multiple currencies like bitcoin, ethereum, etc. When a user clicks on bitcoin tab, exchanges corresponding to it will be show where in form field address can be added and saved. Similarly for ethereum and others. After adding the address and clicking the save button, added address will be shown to the user.

On admin panel, when admin clicks on an address it will show 3 things mainly :-

1. The user it belongs to
2. The currency it is related to
3. What exchange it is

I am able to do 1 (because user is already logged in) and 3 (address added in form field) but cannot add exchange to the saved address.

views.py

```
class ZebpayView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'currencies/addresses.html'

    def get(self, request):
        form = ZebpayForm()
        addresses = Address.objects.all().order_by('-addition_date')  
        users = User.objects.exclude(id=request.user.id) 
        friend = Friends.objects.all().first()
        friends = friend.users.all()

        context = {'form': form, 'addresses': addresses, 'users': users, 'friends': friends}
        return render(request, self.template_name, context)


    def post(self, request):
        form = ZebpayForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            zebpay = form.save(commit=False)
            zebpay.user = request.user
            zebpay.save()
            text = form.cleaned_data['zebpay'] #data filled in form
            form = ZebpayForm()  #show blank form again after one input
            return redirect('currencies:exchanges')

        context = {'form': form, 'text': text}
        return render(request, self.template_name, context)
```

forms.py

```
class ZebpayForm(forms.ModelForm):
    zebpay = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Address'}
    ))

    class Meta:
        model = Address
        fields = ('zebpay',)
```

How do I add name of the currency on which user clicked and saved an address in the exchange field corresponding to it ?

Also, do I need to add currency names in admin panel or make changes in my currency model to add multiple currencies ?

Answer (score 0):

In currency model Make your currency_names as a primary key then you can use as a foreign key into your  address model.

Comment: It is already a foreign key in address model. What I am unable to do is to add the currency_name to the zebpay field in address model which also takes user as a foreign key which I am able to add